# app crashes if not reinstalled after compilation

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xing

When Android studio rebuilds the gradles the app works perfectly fine. Then if I change anything (even juste a space in the code) in my mainactivity the app crashes when I press a "scan" button that should open xing.

I get this error code :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.MYAPP, PID: 8839
              java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method initiateScan()V in class Lcom/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator' appears in /data/data/com.example.MYAPP_e/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex)
```

If I remove the application manually on the phone and recompile again it works.
If I invalide cache and restart Android Studio it works
If I change anything in the build.gradle and sync again it works

Any idea why it doesn't work fine with "run app" when I edit my mainactivity ?

Comment: Try File > Invalidate Caches & Restart

Comment: some code with the method initiateScan()?